# check from text within id tag and add class to another tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have different pages that need a different banner images based on what text is within the id=section-name.  I want to use Javascript or jQuery to check to see what section name the page is using, then add a CSS class to the banner-container id.

This is for a SharePoint 2010 site and will be added to a master page.

Each `aspx` page displays the following `<div>` tag and the section name is dynamically writing into the page.

```
<div id="section-name">*Section name goes here*</div>
```

For example: `<div id="section-name">Toll Stadium</div>`

I then have a `<div id="banner-container"></div>` tag further down the page.

What I need to do is to add a class to the `<div id="banner-container"></div>` based on the section name.

For example:

- if the section-name equals Toll Stadium, then add class banner-toll - `<div id="banner-container" class="banner-toll"></div>`; or
- if the section-name equals Whats On, then add class banner-whatson - `<div id="banner-container" class="banner-whatson"></div>`; or
- if the section-name equals Christmas Festival, then add class banner-xmas - `<div id="banner-container" class="banner-xmas"></div>`
- etc etc

I do not know how to write javascript or jquery at all.  However, I did find some code elsewhere and I have the following code so far.  The only issue is that every page uses the case 0 class (banner-xmas).

```
$(function() {
$('.container')
    .find('#banner-container').each(function(i) {
        switch(i) {
            case 0: 
                $(this).addClass('banner-xmas');
                break;
            case 1: 
                $(this).addClass('banner-whatson');
                break;
            case 2: 
                $(this).addClass('banner-toll');
                break;
            case 3: 
                $(this).addClass('banner-forum');
                break;
            case 4: 
                $(this).addClass('banner-esf');
                break;
            case 5: 
                $(this).addClass('banner-xmas');
                break;
            case 6: 
                $(this).addClass('banner-plan');
                break;
            case 7: 
                $(this).addClass('banner-contact');
                break;
        }
    });
```

I also tried the following but this didn't work either:

```
var objSectionElement = document.getElementById('section-name')
if (objSectionElement != undefined) {
var objSection = objSectionElement.innerHTML.trim();
var objBody = document.body;
if (objSection != undefined && objBody != undefined) {
    if (objSection.startsWith('Default')) {
        objBody.className = objBody.className + " .banner-general";
    }
    else if (objSection.startsWith('What')) {
        objBody.className = objBody.className + " .banner-whatson";
    }
    else if (objSection.startsWith('Toll')) {
        objBody.className = objBody.className + " .banner-toll";
    }
    else if (objSection.startsWith('Forum')) {
        objBody.className = objBody.className + " .banner-forum";
    }
    else if (objSection.startsWith('Endless')) {
        objBody.className = objBody.className + " .banner-esf";
    }
    else if (objSection.startsWith('Christmas')) {
        objBody.className = objBody.className + " .banner-xmas";
    }
    else if (objSection.startsWith('Plan')) {
        objBody.className = objBody.className + " .banner-plan";
    }
    else if (objSection.startsWith('Contact')) {
        objBody.className = objBody.className + " .banner-contact";
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be something that should be done on the server, however it has to be done on the client, consider something like:

```
function addClassBasedOnSection() {
  var classNames = {
    'Default':'banner-general',
    'What':'banner-whatson',
    'Toll':'banner-toll',
    'Forum':'banner-forum',
    'Endless':'banner-esf',
    'Christmas':'banner-xmas',
    'Plan':'banner-plan',
    'Contact':'banner-contact'
  };
  var sectionEl, sectionName, div;
  div = document.getElementById('banner-container');
  sectionEl = document.getElementById('section-name');

  if (sectionEl && div) {
    sectionName = sectionEl.textContent || sectionEl.innerText;
    div.className += ' ' + (classNames[sectionName] || '');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers... BUT I must be doing something totally wrong because I've tried adding all three suggestions to the utility.js file that is referenced on the master page but it doesn't work.  I also tried adding each of the three suggestions to the page but still doesn't work.  Help? Where should the scripts go (i.e. on the page under the section-name div or ????  )

Comment: The code must be run after the page finishes loading (or at the very least, below the "banner-container' div). You can start by putting it in a script element just before the closing body tag.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added this code to just before the closing body tag but it still didn't work. However, I tried OhGodWhy's code and that worked! Thanks...

Comment: It works for me. If you got a working result elsewhere, good for you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    //we pass through a reference to the text within the section name.
    addClassToBanner($('#section-name').text());
});


/*
 * This function needs to be outside of the .ready() scope
 */
function addClassToBanner(txt){
    //avoid assignment issues, create empty variable
    var bannerClass = '';
    switch(txt){
        case 'Toll Stadium':
            bannerClass = 'banner-toll';
            break;
        default:
            bannerClass = 'banner-default';
            break;
    }  
    $('#banner-container').addClass(bannerClass);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I added this code to a js file then added a line of HTML to call the banner-image.js file and it works brilliantly!  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this.

```
<div id="section-name">Toll</div>

$(function(){
    var sectionName = document.getElementById("section-name").innerHTML;
    switch(sectionName) {
        case "xmas":
            $('#banner-container').addClass('banner-xmas');
            break;
        case "whatson":
            $('#banner-container').addClass('banner-whatson');
            break;
        case "toll":
            $('#banner-container').addClass('banner-toll');
            break;
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added this code to just before the closing body tag but it didn't work.  However, I tried OhGodWhy's code and that worked!  Thanks...

Comment: Ya you'd have to tweak the cases to match what your pages were called. Glad you got a solution.